# Looking for some basic level info on adhesive label printing from a web app

Tags: printing, web-applications, thermal-printer

I am looking for a general advice on how to first approach this:

I'm working on a web app that should be able to print adhesive labels. I will be using those smallish printers that use continous (?) label rolls with a width of around 10cm.

I will be sending one label at a time, as they are all different from each other.
They have formatted text, no barcodes, but they might (in the future) have a QR Code (which I can already generate, but I've chosen not to print, yet).

I do not have the printer yet, likely it might be an XPrinter o Brother brand. (It's unlikely it will be Zebra).
The terminals using this to print will be windows based.

I have no prior experience with this sort of printers and some basic conecpts elude me so far:

- How can I review that what I am "designing" on screen will be printed somehow properly? -> I haven't been able to force windows to accept custom sizes for a virtual pdf printer so I am not getting even a preview to work on.
- I read over and over that you can't easily print from a browser to a label printer, but some of that info is old... is that still the case by 2024? is it so for any brand or specific for (i.e.) Zebra printers.
- Do these sort of printer work so different from a laser/inkjet printer which allows me to print from any app as long as it goes through the OS's print manager?

As a side note, I wouldn't mind to put toghether a process like creating adequate PDF files in a folder and automating a job to send that to the printer as long as it works reliably.

Edit: Ok, so based on KJ's comments I wonder if sticking to a very simple "3 lines of plain text" design,would ease my case and I could get away without a Zebra printer (as those are extremely expensive in my country)...

I hope I've worded this properly enough.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some printer vendors probably offer such tools. However, these seem to only apply to printers from that vendor. Please check the support and download pages on the vendor's website.

Comment: ha.. I didn't see this one coming.... thanks for the info @KJ, I updated the question based on that.

Comment: @KJ, thanks a ton for your insights. Yeah, it's mostly peanuts and coffee down here, but mostly coffee :-). The thing is, in the 3rd world those printers become da** expensive compared to a small project like this. 
Anyway, maybe I should clarify that while it is a web application the printing will be done on the client's side. Basically, a user will be loggued in, input an ID, retieve data on screen (name and seat number) and send that to a label pinter attached to his/her terminal (either throug TCP-IP or USB). Pretty much like you would print any ticket from your PC to your local printer.

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure if your previous comments where removed or you consolidated them in you last comment. Anyway, I'm contacting a couple of vendors, and it seems the models I am looking at are bundled with Seagull Driver _(and BarTender but I don't think I have use for that)_ so I'll try to get some answers there. Problem is, most of the time sales ppl don't really know about too much about what they sell.

Comment: @KJ, thanks for all the feedback, you've been very helpful and given me enough confidence on the matter to move forward with the project. Regards.